# Random variable for storing cost to get the target.

Tags: probability, random-variables

There is a simple game for a single player.

Player's initial level is $n$ and player want to get level $m$. If player's level became the target level $m$, the game terminates.

Player should pay $c_i$ to play the game of level $i$ and has probability $p_i$ for winning, $(1-p_i)$ for losing.

If the player won, level-up (+1) and if lose, level-down (-1). Level does not decrease less than 1, of course. (You may consider level starts on $n=1$ only, if this problem is hard to solve.)

I want to know about the total cost for being on level $m$.

I found [Gambler's Ruin Problem](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf), but I can not further apply this simple situation on my case.

Comment: So what happens if a player loses on Level 1?

Comment: @JoeyZou He or she pay for level 1 and stay in level 1.

Comment: "Level starts on $1$" is ambiguous -- it sounds like the initial level is $1$, but you write that the initial level is $n$, so I guess you mean that the *numbering* of the levels starts at $1$?

Comment: By linearity of expectation, the expected cost is the sum over the expected costs for the individual levels, and the expected cost for level $i$ is $c_i$ times the expected number of times that level $i$ is played. The expected number of times that a level $i$ between $n$ and $m$ is played is $\frac1{p_i}\frac1{q_i}$, where $q_i$ is the probability that starting from level $i+1$ level $m$ is reached before level $i$. These latter probabilities might prove difficult to determine in closed form, but you can get them by solving a linear system of equations.

Comment: @joriki Sorry for my mistake. Case of initial level $m$ is more general and "level starts on 1" is the specific case, $m=1$.

Comment: I want to get the distribution of total cost, not only the expected cost.

Comment: That sounds rather difficult. And you should add that to the question.